# I changed an archetype attr (field) name and now I'm getting permission errors. What can I do?

Tags: plone

I named an attribute (field) in a content-type 'string' instead of 'company'.

I've installed my product and after seeing this error, I changed it in my content type class, reinstalled the product, ran update security settings and update catalog. But I keep getting:

```
Module Products.CMFPlone.utils, line 392, in _createObjectByType
Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 290, in _finishConstruction
Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 148, in notifyWorkflowCreated
Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 291, in notifyCreated
Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 346, in notifyCreated
Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 430, in _changeStateOf
Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 529, in _executeTransition
Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 389, in updateRoleMappingsFor
Module Products.DCWorkflow.utils, line 64, in modifyRolesForPermission
Module AccessControl.Permission, line 92, in setRoles
AttributeError: string
```

How do I delete this string attribute that is persisted *somewhere* in ny ZODB since I've already removed it from my content type? I've reinstalled the product, restarted my instance, but I keep getting the same problem. Ideas? I can delete my `Data.fs` since it's a development machine, but if it happened in a production site, this wouldn't be an option.

PS: When I ran `bin/instance fg`:

```
2011-07-28 19:01:59 WARNING Init Class mynamespace.mypackage.content.mycontent.MyContent has a security declaration for nonexistent method 'string'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: @Ross Patterson: I changed to 'delete'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I changed in my content class, but didn't change in my content type interface.

`paster` creates a `# -*- schema definition goes here -*-` on `interfaces.py` as well. I did a `grep string` on my product directory and found it.